# Error: invalid instruction suffix for `cmpxchg'

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to compile another project's code, and I keeping getting `Error: invalid instruction suffix for 'cmpxchg'`. The line of code the error keeps pointing to is:

```
inline bool CAS(long *ptr, long oldv, long newv) {
  unsigned char ret;
  /* Note that sete sets a 'byte' not the word */
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
                "  lock\n"
                "  cmpxchgq %2,%1\n"
                "  sete %0\n"
                : "=q" (ret), "=m" (*ptr)
                : "r" (newv), "m" (*ptr), "a" (oldv)
                : "memory");
  return ret;
}
```

I was wondering if anyone knew what could be the cause of the error and what is a possible solution?

Comment: Are you compiling a 64-bit program?

Comment: I downloaded the project from an academic group and they don't mention it being 64 bit or not

Comment: `q` suffix means quadword -- 64-bit quantity. I doubt it will compile in 32-bit mode. Try compiling the program as 64-bit (`-m64` compiler flag in GCC)

Comment: Not familiar with GCC syntax but I believe the underlying instruction is actually called `cmpxchg8b`, officially - perhaps that mnemonic is supported by GCC? It should work in 32-bit mode.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `cmpxchg` and `cmpxchg8b` (and also `cmpxcgh16b`) are different instructions, and are not synonymous (as `shl` & `sal` are, for example), at least according to [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Developer's Manual: Combined Volumes](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html). Further, `cmpxchg` require 2 parameters, whereas `cmpxchg8b` & `cmpxchg16b` require exactly 1.

Comment: The inline assembly code compiles just fine for _both_ 64bit and 32bit (am using gcc 4.7) if you _don't_ explicitly use `cmpxchgq` but just say `cmpxchg` and let the assembler derive the size from that of the operands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commentors mention, the problem is the 'q' at the end of cmpxchg.  Assemblers use instruction suffix characters to indicate the bit-width when it would otherwise be ambiguous.

This code compiles fine with gcc for a 64-bit target.  You get this output for your cmpxchgq instruction.

```
f0 48 0f b1 16          lock cmpxchg %rdx,(%rsi)
```

That f0 is the LOCK prefix and 48 is the REX.W prefix.  The real opcode is 0f b1.

Compiling for a 32-bit target (gcc option -m32), causes the suffix error.

If you need this code to work on a 32-bit machine, you have a porting headache here.  sizeof(long) is 8 on a 64-bit machine and 4 on a 32-bit machine for Linux.  *IF* and it's a big if, the entire program is resilient enough to tolerate a 'long' going from 8 to 4 bytes, you could get away with just changing the 'q' suffix to an 'l' (that's a lower-case L).  This gives you the '0f b1' instruction in it's 32-bit form:

```
 f0 0f b1 16             lock cmpxchg %edx,(%esi)
```

If not, then you could attempt to rewrite the assembly for a 32-bit target to use CMPXCHG8B which is a different instruction with different register touching behavior.  CMPXCHG8B is not a drop-in replacement!

Comment: You don't have a porting headache - just try it, change the instruction to `cmpxchg` and compile both with `gcc -m64` and `gcc -m32` to see what happens. And no, it's _not ambiguous_ in this situation because the operand size is a full register width both in 32bit and 64bit the way the inline assembly is used here - `sizeof(long)` on 32bit / 64bit is different.

Comment: Admittedly, though, that this code isn't _perfectly_ portable to all conceivable operating system ABIs because the size difference in `long` for 32bit and 64bit isn't guaranteed (by C/C++ language standards). It's true for UN*X on x86/64, which is uses ILP32 / LP64 (that means, `int`, `long` and `...*` being 32bit in 32bit mode, but in 64bit mode, `long` and `...*` are 64bit). It's different on Windows which is ILP32 / IL32P64 so in 64bit mode, `int` and `long` are 32bit while pointers are 64bit.